# Bootstrap image doesn't go center

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to move the image to center but not sure no matter how it just wouldn't happen.

I have a `"container-fluid"`, then wrapped with `"row"` and `"col-md-12"` even tried with `padding:0` and it still doesn't display properly.

Appreciated for any comments.

[image]

Comment: Add `display:table` to that image class and add `width:100%, float:left;` to parent div of the image `col-md-12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add to div this code :

```
<div class = " col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"
```

col-md-12 - for dekstop
col-sm-12 - for tablets
col-xs-12 - for phones

and `margin: 0 auto` isn't work.

Comment: you're right, I need to change to **col-xs-12** and with **margin: 0 auto** in order to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Bootstrap's text-center class.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ... text-center">
   <img ... />
 </div>
</div>
```